# GridView and Stored Procedure?

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, gridview

I want to use a GridView in Visual Studio. I went through the tutorial they have, and I have it set. However I don't see how I can use my Stored Procedure.

It sets me up with this:

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceViewRegistrants" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Events2 %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Registrant]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And I somehow want to replace that `SelectCommand` with a Stored Procedure, as such:

```
sqlCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
sqlCmd.CommandText = "spGetAllRegistrants";
```

I'm not sure where to put this info of `spGetAllRegistrants`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the `SelectCommandType` to **StoredProcedure**:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceViewRegistrants" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Events2 %>" 
SelectCommand="spGetAllRegistrants"
SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```